# How to create reveal image animation effect on hover?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, accordion

Want to create kind of accordion effect but it should give revealing effect as I have done it in the JSFiddle. But the CSS3 animation is buggy - if carefully noticed, the image staggers and gets center on hover. How to achieve it smoothly?

```
.accordion li .accordion-img {
  position:relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}   
.accordion li.active .accordion-img {
  left: -15%;
  width: 130%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sunrays/mzx7kaLd/

**EDIT :** Image should not visibly move on hover. In short, I'm trying to have animation effect like the 2nd section of https://www.airforce.com/

Comment: If you apply only the transitions required (`left` and `width`) instead of `all` you get better performance. Also, if you animate slightly faster then you get less jerky-ness. Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/mzx7kaLd/1/

Comment: Good points. The image is still jerky if I try to make it center. Eg., try with `left:-15%; width:130%;`.

Answer (score 0):

Never use **left, top, right, bottom** when animating. It creates glitches. Rather, use the **transform: translate** property.

I added only one line of code at the following class and you can notice the changes immediately:

```
.accordion li.active .accordion-img {
  transform: translate(-15%, 0px);
  width: 130%;
}
```

Comment: I don't want the images to move visibly like in the 2nd section of https://www.airforce.com/